# OnModelCreating not being called

Tags: c#, entity-framework-4

I have setup one of my machines to have Sql Server 2008 R2 and have put my current database into it.

I then setup a connection string in my app.config like this:

```
<add name="connectionString" connectionString="metadata=res://*;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;Data Source=localhost;Initial Catalog=MyDb;Integrated Security=True;&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

Then in my context constructor I have:

```
public MyDbContext()
    : base("connectionString")
{
}
```

When I do this, OnModelCreating doesn't get called.

How can I tell EntityFramework to use a specific database rather than the default .\sqlexpress?

Answer (score 0):

Well for one I dont think you are correctly calling the base constructor, you would need to do this:

```
public MyDbContext(string connectionString) : base(connectionString)
{

}
```

Or if you dont want to pass in the connection string, you need to use an existing connection string variable:

```
static string connectionString =  // your string here

public MyDbContext() : base(connectionString) { }
```

What are you trying to achieve overall though, is there a need to override ObjectContext like this?

The database that EF references is whats specified in the connection string Data Source and Initial Catalog properties. The Data Source property is what determines which sql instance to reference.

Comment: I guess I should add that I am defining my model using fluent rather than the designer.

Answer (score 0):

The connection string wasn't quite right. Because I am creating the model using fluent (I'm guessing). This is the correct connection string:

```
<add name="connectionString" connectionString="localhost;Initial Catalog=MyDb;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

Comment: Never worked with fluent. I am pretty sure that the constructor you created wouldnt run though, unless fluent has some effect on that. Passing "connectionString" as a literal into the constructor shouldnt do anything -- its not a connection string.

Comment: It's referencing the name of the connectionString in the app.config and it does run.